# Android orientation Change in WebView

Tags: java, android

I am Using Following Code to stop reloading the web page

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


WebView webView;

@Override


protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {


    WebView webView1 = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
     webView1.saveState(outState);


}    

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

    String url="http://www.google.com";


             if (savedInstanceState != null)
                        {
                 ((WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView)).restoreState(savedInstanceState);
                        }
             else{

             webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            String name = MainActivity.this.webView.getTitle();
            TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.title); 

            t.setText(name);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });



    final Activity activity = this;

    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

    final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);


    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Android");
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
    {
         public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                progressDialog.setProgress(0);
                activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);

                progressDialog.incrementProgressBy(progress);

                if(progress > 75)
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
    }
            );


    webView.loadUrl(url);

             }
```

and used `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"` in my manifest file

But when i run it and change orientation of my phone.

The page still get reloaded and progressbar started showing and never dismiss.

can anyone tell me whats wrong in this??

Comment: can you post your layout xml file also. So in mean time i will try to test your code.

Comment: this code is working on gingerbread but not working on ICS

Comment: ICS OS 4.0.0 having some issue. Try on OS 4.0.3 or some other OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the activity is recreated at orientation change. But you can change it by setting `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation` in the declaration of your activity in AndroidManifest.xml and overriding the `onConfigurationChanged()` method of the activity class.

Comment: What did you put in your `onConfigurationChanged()` method ?

Comment: `super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);`

Answer (score 1):

just put this in your manifest activity

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

it's working for me

Answer (score 1):

Please add screenSize also in the manifest android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**in activity tag, manifest**

```
android:screenOrientation="sensor"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

**java**

```
@Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
 super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
 // We do nothing here. We're only handling this to keep orientation
 // or keyboard hiding from causing the WebView activity to restart.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use configChanges attribute for for Activity in manifest file.
So use below code in your Manifest file for each activity.

```
<activity android:name=".YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"/>
```

When you are not using configChanges then `onCreate()` method again called when device orientation change or some other configuration changes.

Comment: comment or remove onConfigurationChanged() from your Activity code

Answer (score 0):

In my code where WebView is in fragment:

In manifest:

```
<activity 
...
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
... />
```

In activity:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

In fragment:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    webView.saveState(outState);
}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState == null)
        webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
    else
        webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

and when orientation change it's change smoothly.